# Where do I declare an instance property in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uikit

I am trying to declare the following instance property for a UITextField object in Objective C:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL clearsOnInsertion;
```

Where would I declare this and properly link it to the text field I created in my main.storyboard so that it will have the desired effect of clearing the text whenever the user begin typing?

Comment: declare it in your .h file and then use it accordingly

Comment: i think based on your question you are trying to set placeholder text and clear it on insert then Text filed have own property called placeholder why you are not use it instead of doing this unnecessary code

Answer (score 1):

A. In general:

It is simply wrong that you have to declare declared properties in the .h file:

a) You have to declare instance properties in an interface. At least there are three types of interfaces:

- The "real", primary (class) interface with `@interface … : …`
- A class continuation `@interface …()`
- A category interface `@interface …(…)`

Wherein `…` is a class name.

b) There is no rule that a interface have to be placed in a .h file. No rule. *Typically* class continuations are located in the .m file. This is what they are for (look at B). *Typically* category interfaces and class interfaces are located in the .h file. But if you want to keep something small private, there is nothing wrong in placing the class interface in an .m file, too.

For the compiler it is without any meaning, because it merges all included headers at the very beginning of compilation and then does not know, where the source code came from. (To be honest, he knows it for better error messages, but his work does not depend on it.)

B. Less general

You have to put an interface at a location, someone who *should* read it, *can* read it. Since properties are often public accessible and .h files are public readable, it is obvious that in many cases putting them into a .h is the right choice. But there is a concept of private properties for information hiding and encapsulation.

C. In your case

In earlier times the IB could only read outlets placed in the .h file. This had the disadvantage that you had to make all outlets public, even there is a private class bundle combination and only the IB should access the outlet.

Starting from version what.ever you can put it into a class continuation in the .m file to keep them private. In many cases this is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it in both .h and .m file
In .h file you can do it like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic) BOOL clearsOnInsertion;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextField tfTextField;
@end
```

To connect outlet goto storyboard open view controller class in assistant editor and press ctrl and drag it to your desired textfield

In .m file you can do it like this

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic) BOOL clearsOnInsertion;

@end

@implementation ViewController
```

And for the effect of clearing the text whenever the user begin typing you need to add the UITextField delegate in .h or .m file and use the delegate methods in your .m file

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@end
```

.m file

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
   clearsOnInsertion = YES;
 }

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
  clearsOnInsertion = NO;
 }

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
  clearsOnInsertion = NO;
 }

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  if(clearsOnInsertion)
  {
    textField.text = @""
    clearsOnInsertion = NO;
  }
}
```